# Databases from Windows to Mac from PHPmyadmin

Tags: windows, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'hv recetly migrated from windows 8 to mac ox x 10.9 maverick. My phpmyadmin data folders and xampp folders are intact with me. Can you suggest me a way to migrate those databases in xampp in mac os x. I had both MyIsam and INNODB databases. Please help! Very important data on stake.

Comment: You might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jaap I am a newbie. Learning. Thanx Anyways.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch 1) I tried to copy mysql folder in /XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql and giving user rights to mysql and admin.  It imported the databases with no tables. 2) I replaced ib_logfile0,ib_logfile1 and ibdata as well for INNODB DB. 3) I hadnt made a mysqldump file in the previous system.

Comment: # Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/   Any changes required in the conf file ? Ihv Tried this [link](http://www.techhack.co.uk/2011/12/30/restore-mysql-database-from-frm-files/) as well. But it stops my phpmyadmin access. Gives this error **#2002 - No such file or directory**

Comment: Only problem is how do i replace my ibdata1 file in my macox mysql directory .Because while replacing mysql stops working. please guide.

Comment: please help me out of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly copying the MySQL "data directory", or the directory on disk where MySQL stores the data files, is not supported. Some people have had some degree of luck doing it, but in particular with InnoDB tables, the data in that folder is not intended for direct transfer. The best chance of success is to completely replace the Mac MySQL data directory with the one from the Windows machine; chances of success when attempting to maintain databases from both systems are minimal. However, doing so may cause issues with your current installation; I highly suggest attempting recovery on a temporary installation/virtual machine, dumping the SQL files, and then importing them permanently to the Mac.

In this case, the best way to handle data recovery would be to boot your Windows system and complete an SQL dump (or export) of the databases so that you can load that in to the Mac. Why direct copying works sometimes and doesn't work others is a mystery to me.